# Change the version of ruby

Tags: ruby, version

I want to change the version of ruby. I'm in a virtual machine.
The current version of ruby is:

```
ruby -v :ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-linux]
gem -v :2.4.3
```

and I want to move to version 2.2.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Rbenv :
https://makandracards.com/makandra/21545-rbenv-how-to-switch-to-another-ruby-version-temporarily-per-project-or-globally

If you're using RVM :
https://rvm.io/rubies/default

If you're not using any of these: `you should be using one of these.`